# Is it possible to create a standalone python script to export "layout" to pdf?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, export, pdf

I have a python script that successfully runs from ArcMap 10.2. I was wondering if it would be possible to rewrite it so that it is a standalone script that prompts the user for the shapefile and then runs some analyses (e.g. buffer, tabulate intersection, intersect, etc.),  changes layer's symbology properties using a preexisting lyr file, zooms to its extent, turns on and off other layers in the mxd TOC template depending on a specific conditions, changes the map title, and finally exports resulting map as a pdf.

The script is quite extensive and although much of the coding can be run as a standalone script, I am wondering if the section of the script dealing with manipulating the layout properties (legend, title) and the layers in the TOC as I want them to look so that I may create a map for exporting as a pdf can be done as a standalone script. It seems to me that some of these actions may only be possible inside an ArcMap session.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [arcpy.mapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Introduction_to_arcpy_mapping/00s300000032000000/)?

Many of the things you're looking to accomplish can be done using this module (e.g. turning layers on and off, changing symbology, etc.). Have a look at the functions list.

However, the team at ESRI has stressed that they aren't trying to expose everything that's available in [ArcObjects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/ArcObjects_Help_for_NET_developers/0001000002zs000000/), so you may find things that you can't do.

Hope that helps,

DR